# What permission required for approval/rejection links

Tags: visualforce, process

What permission is required for approval/rejection links to display

I have the following VFP code

```
 <apex:relatedList list="ProcessSteps" >
     <apex:facet name="header"><b>Approval History</b></apex:facet>
 </apex:relatedList>
```

I want to restrict some user(s) from accessing the approve/reject links, how would I do that

screen shot below:

[image]

Comment: Did you try 'Delegated Approver' field on User record?

Comment: I haven't done this before, I'm new to this topic what exactly do I need to do?

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood your question. It seems that it can be done with some hacks using jquery. You can make 'Approve/Reject' links visible or not depending on your active user. Use SF ajax toolkit to get needed user info in javascript in your page